# Linq mapping list into

Tags: c#, linq, mapping

Can't figure it out but there must be a better way to implement it:

```cs
List<Ticket> results = new List<Ticket>();
var grouped = lines.GroupBy(x => x.TicketNumber);
foreach (var item in grouped)
{
    Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
    ticket.TicketLines = item.Select(g => new TicketLine()
    {
        TicketNumber = g.TicketNumber,
        TicketItem = g.TicketItem,
        Qty = g.Qty,
        ProductNumber = g.ProductNumber
    }).ToList();
    results.Add(ticket);
};
```

Ticket is a class with a single property -> `public List<TicketLine> TicketLines { get; set; }`

In other words, I want the below set:
ticket, ticket item, qty, product

```
1,1,5,12345
1,2,1,32323
2,1,3,22222
2,2,8,33333
```

mapped into the list of two tickets where each contains two items.

The code snippet does the job however I'm sure there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: Why do you want a better way? Creating a single linq query will make the code harder to understand and will run in same amount of time and memory.  The code the way it is will be easier to comment.

Comment: You are looking for a better way, but what exactly are your criteria of "better"? If you don't tell these to us, this question is opinion-based.

Comment: How will `results` be consumed? Do you require a `List` or simply an `IEnumerable`?

Comment: the items in lines object are TicketLine class also ? In this case you're making some clones. To clone serializable object I use an extension : var str = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj, options); var newObj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(str, options); You can also make a clone method with reflexion if your objects are not serializable
But if it's not the same class, you can use AutoMapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
var results = lines
    .GroupBy(x => x.TicketNumber)
    .Select(g => new Ticket {
            TicketNumber = g.Key,
            TicketLines = g.ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Nice and clean is better than foreach loop I've done ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So you have a sequence of `Lines`, where every `Line` has at least properties `TicketNumber`, `TicketItem` and `ProductNumber`

You want to make groups of Lines that have the same TicketNumber. For every group you want to make exactly one object of class `Ticket`. This Ticket contains a List of `TickeLines`, one TicketLine for every Line in the group.

So Every TicketLine in the Ticket corresponds with one Line. It contains the following property values

- TicketNumber: the common TicketNumber of all Lines in the group
- TicketItem: the value of property TicketItem of the corresponding Line
- Qty is the number of Lines in the group,
- ProductNumber: the value of property ProductNumber of the corresponding Line.

After this rather large introduction about your requirements, the code is simple. I use the overload of [Enumerable.GroupBy that has a parameter resultSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3__)

```
var tickets = lines.GroupBy(line => line.TicketNumber, 

// parameter resultSelector: use the common ticketNumber and all Lines that have this
// ticketNumber to make exactly one Ticket object
(ticketNumber, linesWithThisTicketNumber) => new Ticket
{
    // for every Line in this group, make one TicketLine:
    TicketLines = linesWithThisTicketNumber.Select(line => new TickeLine
    {
         TicketNumber = ticketNumber,
         TicketItem = line.TicketItem,
         Qty = linesWithThisTicketNumber.Count(),
         ProductNumber = line.ProductNumber,
    })
    .ToList(),
});
```

**Room for improvement**

The above is not very efficient. The TicketNumber and Qty for every TicketLine in a Ticket will have the same value. Are you sure you want this? The following seems more logical:

```
// parameter resultSelector: use the common ticketNumber and all Lines that have this
// ticketNumber to make exactly one object
(ticketNumber, linesWithThisTicketNumber) => new
{
    TicketNumber  = ticketNumber,
    
    // for every Line in this group, make one TicketLine:
    TicketLines = linesWithThisTicketNumber.Select(line => new
    {
         TicketItem = line.TicketItem,
         ProductNumber = line.ProductNumber,
    })
    .ToList(),
});
```

The result is a sequence of object, where every object has a TicketNumber and a List of objects with data extracted from the Lines that have this TicketNumber. The number of elements in the list is the Qty.

Apart from the advantage that the Qty is calculated only once, you won't store duplicate values.

Imaging what would happen if someone decides to add a TicketLine:

```
var tickets = ... // see original answer
tickets[0].TickedLines.Add(new TicketLine());
```

Is the value of Qty still correct in this scenario?